# How to Categoriy and Product XML files combined

Tags: php, xml, file, foreach

This is my Categories XML file. category levels from top to bottom :

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <category id="17" name="Off-Road" />
        <category id="141" name="HPI - Maverick" />
        <category id="453" name="HSP" />
        <category id="412" name="Diger" />
    </category>
    <category>
        <category id="124" name="Benzinli" />
        <category id="125" name="Off-Road" />
        <category id="295" name="MCD Racing" />
        <category id="315" name="RTR" />
        <category id="316" name="Kit Versiyonları" />
    </category>
</categories>
```

This is my Product XML file. Have only category id:

```
<products>
<product>
    <id>001300V4</id>
    <name>MCD RRV4 Competition - No Engine</name>
    <price>1049</price>
    <stock>2</stock>
    <currency>Euro</currency>
    <brand>MCD Racing</brand>
    <description> 
        <![CDATA[......]]> ]]>
    </description>
    <categories>
        <category>316</category>
    </categories>
</product>
```

How can combined that two files and convert only one xml file? Please help me. Thanks.

I need final xml :

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>001300V4</id>
        <name>MCD RRV4 Competition - No Engine</name>
        <price>1049</price>
        <stock>2</stock>
        <currency>Euro</currency>
        <brand>MCD Racing</brand>
        <description><![CDATA[......]]></description>
        <categories>
            <category>Benzinli</category>
            <category>Off-Road</category>
            <category>MCD Racing</category>
            <category>Kit Versiyon</category>
        </categories>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: In our final xml you put 4 <category> tag, with what criteria? in “Product XML” i can see only 1 category with id 316, so I expect to insert in final xml only `<category>Kit Versiyonları</category>` (id=316). Can you explain criteria of inclusion?

Comment: In addition, either your xml are invalid. Can double-check it and re-edit the post?

Comment: Top category <category id="124" name="Benzinli" /> and sub category <category id="125" name="Off-Road" /> etc...

Comment: each product in origin have only one category?

Comment: Yes each product only one category.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath, you can try this script:

```
/* Init DOMDocuments: */                                                        #01
$categories = new DOMDocument();
$product    = new DOMDocument();

/* Load XML: */
$categories ->loadXML( $xml1, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$product    ->loadXML( $xml2, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$categories ->formatOutput = True;
$product    ->formatOutput = True;

/* Init xPath: */
$xPathCat   = new DOMXPath( $categories );
$xPathProd  = new DOMXPath( $product );

/* Search Product Category: */                                                  #02
$prodCat = $xPathProd->query( '/products/product/categories/category' );

if( $prodCat->length > 0 )                                                      #03
{
    $cat = $prodCat->item(0);

    /* Search Corresponding Category in Categories: */                          #04
    $found = $xPathCat->query
    ( "/categories/category/category[@id=\"{$cat->nodeValue}\"]" );
    
    if( $found->length )
    {
        foreach( $found->item(0)->parentNode->childNodes as $child )            #05
        {
            /* Append ChildNode <category>Category Name</category>: */
            $cat->parentNode->appendChild
            (
                $product->createElement( 'category', $child->getAttribute( 'name' ) )
            );
        }
        /* Remove Old Category (numeric): */                                    #06
        $cat->parentNode->removeChild( $cat );
    }
}

echo $product->saveXML().PHP_EOL;
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/mtUcg)**</kbd>

1. We create one `DOMDocument` for categories, one for product; then we load respective XML (you have to change `$xml1` and `$xml2` with your variable names; if you want to load it directly from file, you have to use `->load( filePath )` instead of `->loadXML( var )`); at the end, we init two `DOMXPath` for performing easy queries;
2. We perform a xPath query to found the nodes `/products/product/categories/category` in the product xml;
3. If the query is successful, we process first category item (this script omits eventually additional category items, although it is possible to adapt it to works also with more than one), and
4. We perform a xPath query to found the product category id in the categories xml (`category[@id=`);
5. If the query is successful, we process each category node sibling, retrieving his attribute 'name', that we use at node value of new `<category>` product element, then we append this new element to last sibling of actual `<category>` product element;
6. After the `foreach` loop, we remove the original, numeric `<category>` product element and print out resulting XML.

---

- see more about [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
- see more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

---

#### Edit:

Your *categories* file is different from provided example. In addition, as you can see above at §3, my script works only on first product category match. To run properly with your files change the script above in this way:

```
(...)
/* Search Product Category: */
foreach( $xPathProd->query( '/products/product/categories' ) as $node )
{
    $prodCat = $xPathProd->query( './category', $node );
    if( $prodCat->length > 0 )
    {
        $cat = $prodCat->item(0);
        $found = $xPathCat->query( "//category[@id=\"{$cat->nodeValue}\"]" );
        if( $found->length )
        {
            foreach( $found->item(0)->parentNode->childNodes as $child )
            {
                /* Append ChildNode <category>Category Name</category>: */
                $cat->parentNode->appendChild
                (
                    $product->createElement( 'category', htmlspecialchars($child->getAttribute( 'name' )) )
                );
            }
            /* Remove Old Category (numeric): */
            $cat->parentNode->removeChild( $cat );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i will try now.

Comment: how can fix following error:Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 in

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in ....

Comment: Ok i used lod (filePath) and saved xml but not contain category names. :(

Comment: @HakanBulentUstun ‘Start tag expected, '<' not found’ means that the xml is malformed.

Comment: Ok fixed start tag expected problem. But can not save combined xml file. Only save product.xml file.

Comment: `file_put_contents( 'YourNewFilePath.xml', $product->saveXML() )`

Comment: Yes i did. But filan xml file same product file

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain. BTW, `$categories` and `$product` are not files, are objects. your original files remain unchanged, unless you overwrite it.

Comment: $category_dosyasi_orj="https://hobiall.com/xml/categories.xml"; //Kategori dosyasının xml linki
$products_dosyasi_orj="https://hobiall.com/xml/products.xml"; //Ürün dosyasının xml linki
$final_xml="/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/hobiall/public/xml/final.xml"; // Save path and file name  Script Link: https://hobiall.com/xml/xml_combine.php Final XML Link: https://hobiall.com/xml/final.xml (but same product file)

Comment: @HakanBulentUstun see my edited answer. btw, this is not a free code production, but a community to help coding problem. You never learn php by copy-and-paste. Try some tutorial first, and try to understand every command you type. If you doesn't understand it, find it on php documentation

Comment: Full correctly it does not work. But I can fix it a little agonizing. I thank you for your help.

Comment: Excuse me but dosent work category names. Because must add only parent categories, but added all same level category, Please help me :( Sample category:number <category id="480" name="Hobi Grubu">
<category id="247" name="Tank">

<category id="379" name="VsTank"/>
</category>
<category id="294" name="Infrared"/>
</category>
<category id="4" name="Tekne">

</category>
<category id="42" name="Yakıtlı (Nitrolu)"/>


</category>
<category id="372" name="Buhar Makinesi">

</category>
<category id="359" name="Taş Ev Maketleri"/>

Comment: FALSE: 
<categories>
      <category>Tank</category>
      <category>Tekne</category>
      <category>Buhar Makinesi</category>
      <category>Taş Ev Maketleri</category>
      <category>Puzzle</category>
      <category>Statik Motorlar</category>
      <category>Gadget</category>
      <category>Ahşap Gemi Kitleri</category>
      <category>Dekoratif Tekne</category>
      <category>İş Makinesi</category>
    </categories>

Comment: TRUE:  <categories>
      <category>Hobi Grubu</category>
      <category>Taş Ev Maketleri</category>
    </categories>